# Load functions with all variable names. Is there another way?

Tags: ruby, function

Is there a better way to do this?

```
value = 10
train = []
storage = 12
another_var = 'apple'

def first_function(value, train, storage, another_var)
    second_function(train, storage)
    third_function(train, storage, another_var)
    forth_function(value, another_var)
end

def third_function(train, storage, another_var)
    puts  'x'
end

def second_function(train, storage)
    puts  'x'
end

def forth_function(value, another_var)
    puts  'x'
end
```

Is this the proper way to do this? Taking the values along for the ride?  I'm working my way through LRTHW and I'm trying to build a game. The problem I am running into is that I have a for loop that represents turns and that acts as the game driver. Inside of that for loop it calls functions that then call more functions. Unless I load all the variables into the first function and then pass them down the chain it breaks. It's sort of neat that it blocks you from accessing variables outside of the very narrow scope, but is there a way I can override this?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to accomplish? This may or may not be a good approach depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Noah, I just saw LRTHW for the first time, and I think it looks like a poor way to learn ruby.  The pickaxe book is much more rubyish, jumping into classes immediately:  http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/   Classes are not a higher level function of ruby, they are fundamental!  Many of the problems you have posted in relation to this game project would be much better solved in an OO manner with classes.

Comment: @DGM. I think you're right. My understanding is the Ruby is a OO language fundamentally. I'm almost done with this piece anyway, I'll finish the LRTHW.

Comment: But to be fair to LRTHW, the lesson assignment was to expand out the game from the previous game. I sort of went in a different direction, because I'm a huge strategy type of guy and less let's walk through rooms type of guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use instance variables to keep them in scope without having to pass them as parameters every time.

```
@value = 10
@train = []
@storage = 12
@another_var = 'apple'

def first_function
    second_function
    third_function
    fourth_function
end

def third_function
    puts  @another_var
end

def second_function
    puts  @value + @storage
end

def fourth_function
    puts  @train
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to be able to do all combinations of optional parameters.

Try this:

```
def myfunction(options={})
    options = {:value => 10, :train => [], :storage => 12, :another_var => 'apple'}.merge(options)
    puts options[:value]
    puts options[:train]
    puts options[:storage]
    puts options[:another_var]
end
```

Example usage:

```
irb(main):013:0> myfunction({})
10
12
apple
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> myfunction({:value => 11, :storage => 23})
11
23
apple
=> nil
```

Comment: This is a cleaner way to do what I'm already doing, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You're trying to design an API that lets you pick sensible defaults and only pass in what you need, right? The hash method for optional params is the cleaner way.